# ntpstat showing different servers when run at different times

Tags: ntp

`ntpstat
 synchronised to NTP server (IP addr redacted) at stratum 5 
   time correct to within 180 ms
   polling server every 1024 s`

If I come back at a later time and run `ntpstat`, the result will sometimes return with a different IP address where I've put `IP addr redacted`.

Is this the result of `polling server every xs`? So, if it detects some threshold of drift/discrepancy every 17 minutes, it will sync to another server in the pool that is defined in `/etc/ntp.conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `ntpd -np`. You should see several servers listed, and it's probably just your local system synchronising to different servers at different times.

Here's an example from a system I manage, showing that my local server is currently synchronised to a GPS-based Stratum 1 source.

```
ntpq -pn
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
-10.9.x.x        212.129.x.x      3 s  603 1024  377   13.064    0.807   9.205
-51.255.x.x      92.243.x.x       3 u  931 1024  377   11.978    0.718   2.892
*82.64.x.x       .GPS.            1 u  584 1024  377   17.798   -0.375  20.971
```

Comment: I just verified the same behavior as you have listed. This makes sense, I was making sure there wasn't something broken or misconfigured on my side. Thank you @roaima.